# Method to act on parameter or from iterable if not parameters are passed

Tags: python, sql, meta-programming

The scenario is as follows. The API of my program will allow the user to perform some method on a particular element (let's say a tuple from a database). If this parameter is not passed to the function, then the "default" behavior is to look for a list of elements (from a database query, for example) and to act on all of them. Like this:

```
task(simple_object) # will process simple_object
task() # query the database with some previously defined query
```

And this is what I did (implementation in Python):

```
@task(query='SELECT * FROM User WHERE age < 18')
def task_disable_account(user):
    disable_user(user)
```

This way I can call the `task_disable_account` with one particular `User` or I can call it with no arguments and then every tuple from the SQL query will be processed. The definition of `task` decorator is as follows:

```
task_registry = []
def task(query):
    Task = namedtuple('Task', ['func', 'query'])
    def decorate(func):
        def queried(*_args):
            if not _args:
                map(func, search(query)) # execute on result from SQL
                return
            return func(*_args) # execute on 1 passed parameter
        task_registry.append(Task(queried, query))
        return queried
    return decorate
```

And this is how I use it (just an example, actual code is more complicated):

```
def main(): # lets assume a main() function
    for func, _ in task_registry:
        # I'm getting and ID from sys.argv and returning a User object
        # If not passed via arguments, call function with no parameters
        user = get_from_argv()
        if user:
            func(user)
        else:
            func()
```

The idea behind all this is:

1. The `task`ed method should only take care of the processing of 1 element, centralising the way we search for, and how we iterate over them.
2. Make it easy to add new `task` methods to our implementation, not having to repeat the boilerplate code over and over.

Comment: You append to the `task_registry`… but where or how do you ever use it?

Comment: I added a small example usage. @200_success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not going into the question as to whether or not this is a good idea, I can see very little wrong with the solution.

One thing I would very much like to suggest is the following.

Instead of

```
map(func, search(query))
```

please write

```
for result in search(query):
    func(result)
```

There are actually some differences:

- In Python 3, `map` builds a iterable, and `func(result)` will only be called if the iterable is looped over. In this case, this is most definitely not what you want!
- In Python 2, `map` builds a list, and thus evaluates everything. Better, but an intermediate list is now going to be build and thrown away.

In general I would recommend **only** using `map` for functions that are side-effect free.

Another thing I'd like to remark is where you build the `namedtuple`. You do it inside the function, building a new `Task` class for every task you add. Please move that code outside of the function `task`.